# How to use immutability-helper to update nested objects in array?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, immutability

I have an array of objects, and analysis is also an array of objects.

```
const products = [
    {
        id: '111',
        analysis: [
            { id: 1, value: 51 },
            { id: 2, value: 40 },
            { id: 3, value: 25 }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: '222',
        analysis: [
            { id: 1, value: 77 },
            { id: 2, value: 99 },
            { id: 3, value: 22 }
        ]
    }
]
```

I'm new to immutability-helper. I have an array `operations` which indicates how to update `products` array.

```
const operations = [
    { id: '111', analysisId: 1, value: 10 },
    { id: '111', analysisId: 3, value: 4 },
    { id: '222', analysisId: 3, value: 88 }
];
```

So this means I want to find the object with `id = 111`, and then find `analysisId = 1`, and finally update the value from 51 to 10. Then I will need to do the same thing for the rest 2 operations. I don't want to mutate `products` array. Would someone help me? Thanks!

Comment: Your `products` is not initialized as an `Immutable` object ?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know they only way to do it is find the indexes before doing the update

```
operations.map(operation => {
    var indexOfProduct = products.findIndex(x => x.id === operation.id);
    var indexOfAnalysis = products[indexOfProduct].analysis.findIndex(a => a.id === operation.analysisId);
    products = update(products, {
        [indexOfProduct]: {
            analysis: {
                [indexOfAnalysis]: {
                    value: {$set: operation.value}
                    }                   
                }
            }
        })  
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't deduct from their docs that we should pass indexOfProduct as [indexOfProduct].